# Path of session variables on server

Tags: php, variables, session

How to get complete path of session variables stored on server in php. Even though I used phpinfo() method,I could not find out.

Comment: there is no path. they're just stored in $_SESSION. if you want the location of the session **FILE**, then [session_save_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php)

Answer (score 0):

The $_SESSION variable storage is determined by PHP's session.save_path configuration. Normally this is /tmp on a Linux/Unix PC. Use the phpinfo() function to view your particular settings :

check PHP documentation:

http://us.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path